# How to extract consistent year from timestamptz

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to use the Postgres function `extract()` to get the year from a `timestamptz` column, but get unexpected results. I expected that it would use UTC, but appears to use whatever the local timezone of the system is (EST in my case). How do I get the `extract` function to return UTC regardless of what the timezone of the timestamp or the system is?

Example 1:

```
testdb=# create table foo ( t timestamptz check( extract(year from t)::int = 2013) );

testdb=# \d foo
              Table "public.foo"
 Column |           Type           | Modifiers
--------+--------------------------+-----------
 t      | timestamp with time zone |
Check constraints:
    "foo_t_check" CHECK (date_part('year'::text, t)::integer = 2013)

testdb=# insert into foo values ('2013-01-01 01:49:05.048+00');
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "foo_t_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2012-12-31 20:49:05.048-05).
```

Example 2:

```
testdb=# SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM '01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC+01'::timestamp with time zone);
 date_part
-----------
      1969
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `at time zone`

```
create table foo (
    t timestamptz
    check (extract(year from t at time zone 'UTC') = 2013)
);

select extract(year from
    '01-01-1970 00:00:00 utc+01'::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'utc'
    );
 date_part 
-----------
      1970
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this:

```
extract(year from t::timestamp with time zone)
```

working example:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM 
               '01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC+01'::timestamp 
               with time zone)
```

returns `1970`

Comment: This is returning 1969 for me instead of 1970 - I'm using the official Postgres.org 9.2 build for Ubuntu 10.04. I've edited my question to include your test.

Comment: @Petriborg going to need some more info outside of "this isnt working"